# Can multiple cetacean species communicate?

Tags: zoology, ethology, community-ecology, communication

It seems that individuals within the same species have their own communication, but is there evidence to suggest that individuals from different species are able to communicate?

Comment: We are starting a Bioacoustics Stack Exchange for people interested in the studies of non-human animal sounds and the impacts of sounds on animals. Please join us! https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/126698/bioacoustics?referrer=YjZmYjUxYzJkNDI1YmY5NDk3NzdhMzViMmZlNzI4ZDdiYTAyMWQxNTM5ZWFiNzRhODNkMmFiMzIxZjI3MmY1N_gFvrICTvBsmYNJ2ptRM6lIZEAV-VGkXtIwNyVDja680

Answer (score 6):

Do dogs and humans communicate? What about cats and dogs? I think defining "communicate" is the real question here.

This 2012 [study](https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0052201) claims to show "the first experimental evidence that the interception of heterospecific vocalizations can mediate interactions between different cetacean species in previously unrecognized ways". In other word, one species is recognizing and responding to the vocalizations of another.

[This article](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/false-killer-whales-and-bottlenose-dolphins-swim-together-for-years/) points out that "...false killer whales and bottlenose dolphins choose to spend time with specific members of the other species rather than randomly mixing or engaging in brief opportunistic encounters" How could this occur without some form of "communication"? I'd argue it couldn't,

Comment: to be fair the second one does not require communication just the ability to recognize individuals in the other species.

Comment: It's a reciprocal relationship that involves interpreting signs and signals from the other. What is the threshold at which "recognition" becomes "communication"?

Comment: I can avoid riding ornery horses a second time that does not mean I was communicating with the horse, I can prefer my cat to my neighbors cat that pisses on my car, but again it does not mean I am communicating with it.  Favoritism is not necessarily communication.

Comment: "I can avoid riding ornery horses a second time that does not mean I was communicating with the horse" Is not the horse's "orneriness" a non-verbal form of communication that it does not want to be ridden? It's not Shakespeare but the threshold in biology for "communication" is quite basic--if a cell emits a signaling molecule and another cell receives it, we call that communication even thought it's nothing more than "recognition".

Comment: If you define communication that broadly then the question more or less breaks down, any behavior that impacts another organisms can be communication. Communication does not have only a single biological definition.

Comment: And if you proscribe communication so broadly then the question likewise breaks down.FWIW, saying that interspecific congregation behaviors mediated through vocal cues is definitively NOT a form of communication is refuted by the opening sentence from Wikipedia's definition of [Animal communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Animal_communication).

Comment: making a big leap from what I said to that, interspecific congregation behaviors mediated through vocal cues is definitively not what I was referring to, it is neither of my examples. Also wikipedia is not a scientific source.

Comment: I have been trying to have a discussion here but you appear refractory to much beyond defending your ego. I cited WIkipedia because the claim you are making is so fundamentally wrong that I thought a more general source might help you. Guess not. Okay, here's [a recent peer reviewed paper](https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/full/10.1098/rspb.2017.2676) discussing a terrestrial analog to the whale example that you took issue with. Unsurprisingly, they consider this to be a form of "communication" as well.